# Strange NaN values for loss function (MLP) in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I hope you can help me. I'm implementing a small multilayer perceptron using **TensorFlow** and a few tutorials I found on the internet. The problem is that the net is able to learn something, and by this I mean that I am able to somehow optimize the value of the training error and get a decent accuracy, and that's what I was aiming for. However, I am recording with Tensorboard some strange NaN values for the loss function. Quite a lot actually. Here you can see my latest Tensorboard recording of the loss function output. Please all those triangles followed by discontinuities - those are the NaN values, note also that the general trend of the function is what you would expect it to be.

**Tensorboard report**
[image: Evolution of my loss function in Tensorboard, those triangles are the NaN values]

I thought that a high learning rate could be the problem, or maybe a net that's too deep, causing the gradients to explode, so I lowered the learning rate and used a single hidden layer (this is the configuration of the image above, and the code below). Nothing changed, I just caused the learning process to be slower.

**Tensorflow Code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import scipy.io, sys, time
from numpy import genfromtxt
from random import shuffle

#shuffles two related lists #TODO check that the two lists have same size
def shuffle_examples(examples, labels):
    examples_shuffled = []
    labels_shuffled = []
    indexes = list(range(len(examples)))
    shuffle(indexes)
    for i in indexes:
        examples_shuffled.append(examples[i])
        labels_shuffled.append(labels[i])
    examples_shuffled = np.asarray(examples_shuffled)
    labels_shuffled = np.asarray(labels_shuffled)
return examples_shuffled, labels_shuffled

# Import and transform dataset
dataset = scipy.io.mmread(sys.argv[1])
dataset = dataset.astype(np.float32)

all_labels  = genfromtxt('oh_labels.csv', delimiter=',')
num_examples    = all_labels.shape[0]

dataset, all_labels = shuffle_examples(dataset, all_labels)

# Split dataset into training (66%) and test (33%) set
training_set_size = 2000
training_set = dataset[0:training_set_size]
training_labels = all_labels[0:training_set_size]
test_set = dataset[training_set_size:num_examples]
test_labels = all_labels[training_set_size:num_examples]

test_set, test_labels = shuffle_examples(test_set, test_labels)

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 150
mini_batch_size = 100
total_batch = int(num_examples/mini_batch_size)

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 50 # 1st hidden layer of neurons
#n_hidden_2 = 16 # 2nd hidden layer of neurons
n_input = int(sys.argv[2]) # number of features after LSA
n_classes = 2;

# Tensorflow Graph input
with tf.name_scope("input"):
    x = tf.placeholder(np.float32, shape=[None, n_input], name="x-data")
    y = tf.placeholder(np.float32, shape=[None, n_classes], name="y-labels")

print("Creating model.")

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    with tf.name_scope("h_layer_1"):
        # First hidden layer with SIGMOID activation
        layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
        layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_1)
    #with tf.name_scope("h_layer_2"):
        # Second hidden layer with SIGMOID activation
        #layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
        #layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_2)
    with tf.name_scope("out_layer"):
        # Output layer with SIGMOID activation
        out_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']), biases['bout'])
        out_layer = tf.nn.sigmoid(out_layer)
    return out_layer

# Layer weights
with tf.name_scope("weights"):
    weights = {
        'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], stddev=0.01, dtype=np.float32)),      
        #'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], stddev=0.05, dtype=np.float32)),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_classes], stddev=0.01, dtype=np.float32))
}

# Layer biases 
with tf.name_scope("biases"):
    biases = {
        'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], dtype=np.float32)),
        #'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], dtype=np.float32)),
        'bout': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes], dtype=np.float32))
    }

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
with tf.name_scope("adam"):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Define summaries
tf.scalar_summary("loss", cost)
summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()

print("Model ready.")

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    board_path = sys.argv[3]+time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")+"/"
    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(board_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())   

    print("Starting Training.")
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        training_set, training_labels = shuffle_examples(training_set, training_labels)
        for i in range(total_batch):
            # example loading
            minibatch_x = training_set[i*mini_batch_size:(i+1)*mini_batch_size]
            minibatch_y = training_labels[i*mini_batch_size:(i+1)*mini_batch_size]
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op
            _, summary = sess.run([optimizer, summary_op], feed_dict={x: minibatch_x, y: minibatch_y})
            # Write log
            writer.add_summary(summary, epoch*total_batch+i)

    print("Optimization Finished!")

# Test model
test_error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
accuracy = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(accuracy, np.float32))
test_error, accuracy = sess.run([test_error, accuracy], feed_dict={x: test_set, y: test_labels})
print("Test Error: " + test_error.__str__() + "; Accuracy: " + accuracy.__str__())
print("Tensorboard path: " + board_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post the solution here just in case someone gets stuck in a similar way. If you see that plot very carefully, all of the NaN values (the triangles) come on a regular basis, like if at the end of every loop something causes the output of the loss function to just go NaN. 
The problem is that, at every loop, I was giving a mini batch of "empty" examples. The problem lies in how I declared my inner training loop:

```
for i in range(total_batch):
```

Now what we'd like here is to have Tensorflow go through the entire training set, one minibatch at a time. So let's look at how total_batch was declared:

```
total_batch = int(num_examples / mini_batch_size)
```

That is not quite what we'd want to do - as we want to consider the training set **only**. So changing this line to:

```
total_batch = int(training_set_size / mini_batch_size)
```

Fixed the problem.
It is to be noted that Tensorflow seemed to ignore those "empty" batches, computing NaN for the loss but not updating the gradients - that's why the trend of the loss was one of a net that's learning something.